# How to re-organise this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Many dataframe is concatenated to get a dataframe.The resulting dataframe look like follows

```
timestamp CC A0 B0 C0 CA CD  CC A1 B1 C1 CA CD  CC A2 B2 C2 CA CD
          10 <---values--->  <-----------no values ------------->
          15 <---values--->  <-----------no values ------------->
          16 <---values--->  <-----------no values ------------->
          18 <---values--->  <-----------no values ------------->
 values   <---no values--->  8 <---values--->   <---no values--->
          <---no values--->  9 <---values--->   <---no values--->
          <---no values--->  14<---values--->   <---no values--->
          <---no values--->  19<---values--->   <---no values--->
          <-----------no values ------------->   2 <---values--->
          <-----------no values ------------->   5 <---values--->
          <-----------no values ------------->   7 <---values--->
          <-----------no values ------------->   21<---values--->
```

**CC A0 B0 C0 CA CD** are part of **dataframe 1**,  **CC A1 B1 C1 CA CD** are part of **dataframe 2** and **CC A2 B2 C2 CA CD** are part of **dataframe 3** before concatenation**

timestamp is the index of dataframe

I want to organise this data frame as below

```
timestamp CC A0 B0 C0   A1 B1 C1  A2 B2 C2 CA CD
          2   
          5 
          7 
          8 
 values   9
          10
          14
          15
          16
          18
          19
          21
```

Comment: How did you concatenate the dataframes? It looks like you did not use the right method. There are plenty of ways to concatenate dataframes. Have a look at this on the pandas doc. (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: new_dataframe = pd.concat(list1,axis= 1)@robinood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you concatenated your dataframes.
The argument axis=1 means that you want your concatenation happening on the columns, where here you want to have your rows being concatenated and your columns being merged.
I suggest you simply use :

`new_dataframe = pd.concat(list1).sort_index()`

and it should concatenate your dataframes the way you want it and sort your values according to your indexes.

I'm not sure if CC is your index or not, but if you want to sort the dataframe according to the CC columns you can also apply:

```
new_dataframe = new_dataframe.sort_values("CC")
```

Comment: i need the index. the final data must in a way the value of index goes on increasing or  CC must sart from lowest and end with highest

Comment: after this concat, do i need to do a sorting?or is it possible inside the concat?

Comment: You do need a sort after the concat, either on the index or on the CC column (i am not sure if your CC column is the index or not). I updated the answer.